# Leaflet geolocation alternative for if access is denied

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, mapping, geolocation

I have the following that prompts the user to give location access. On granting permission the user's location is shown and the map loads. I'm trying to find a solution for if the user accidentally denies location access. Can anyone advise?

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 4;

  L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
  alert(e.message);
}

map.on("locationfound", onLocationFound);
map.on("locationerror", onLocationError);

map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16 });
```

Comment: And what's the problem you're trying to solve, exactly?

Comment: hi @IvanSanchez - problem is that if the user denies access the map doesn't load. The dream scenario would be that if that happens, the map still shows at a certain coordinate.

Comment: (1) What code are you usign for initializing the map? Any initial `setView`? (2) What would be that *certain coordinate*?

Comment: @IvanSanchez var map = L.map("map", {
        centre: [51.450584 , -2.5946832],
        zoom: 12,
        zoomControl: false
        });

Comment: Despite my love for british english, [the Leaflet option is spelt `center`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-center) and not `centre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there with the answer.

The 'Certain Coordinate' value just needs to be a meaningful and useful location. If the map you are building is for a specific City, maybe set it to the CBD.

Or if its a global map, set it to 0,0 at a high map scale (I think Google Earth desktop app does this)

You should do this in your onLocationError function, something like this

```
function onLocationError(e) {
L.map("map", { center: [51.450584 , -2.5946832], zoom: 12, zoomControl: false });
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response, could give an example of how that would look using the code above?

Comment: edited my answer, to include some code. copied your L.map code from a comment above.

Comment: Perfect - it was the spelling of center. All sorted.